# Filtering Facebook users Profile feeds by updated_time

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Good day!

I am using Facebook graph API to retrieve Facebook users Profile feed (Wall) information.
My query will be:
    https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/feed?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN_OF_MY_FB_APPLICATION
Through this, I was able to retrieve users wall information with created_time and updated_time.

I found from http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/, that we can filter information by created_time using **since** and **until** parameters.

Is there any way through which I can filter users Profile information by updated_time?

Thank you.

Comment: Can anyone please suggest me whether its possible or not? Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Facebook Graph API search using since updated\_time parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30818119/facebook-graph-api-search-using-since-updated-time-parameter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible using [FQL](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/).

For example, modifying [an example](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream/)  on the Facebook Developers site, you can retrieve the current user's posts to the her wall/feed updated before December 30, 2009 at 12am EST like so:

```
SELECT post_id, actor_id, target_id, message FROM stream WHERE source_id = me() 
AND updated_time < 1262196000 LIMIT 50
```

To my knowledge you can't filter by updated_time using the Graph API.

Comment: Thank you Gunnar. I too think the same. Already I have tried with FQL as you mentioned and was successfully retrieving information by updated_time. But when I try through Graph API, I wasn't. Thank you again.

Comment: Warning: As mentioned in link "FQL is still available in version 2.0, but will not be available in the next version of the API. This early warning is given so that developers can start migrating off FQL to the Graph API as soon as possible. We strongly recommend that developers build no new experiences based on FQL." developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

Comment: thank you Gunnar , i want to know it is possible with graph api with out FQL