# Graph Api : How to scan Facebook new page feeds and modified feed

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am making a Facebook application which dynamically adds a tab on Facebook page with manage_pages and read_mailbox permission. My application gets page wall feed and stores in database using the graph feed api.

Now what i want to do is scan the feed everyday and get the new feed added to page and also the modified feed i.e. the previous feed which has got new comments.Any one has idea how to make this query using the graph api for new feed only and previous modified feed only.

Comment: Have you checked feed data for "**created_time**" and "**updated_time**" ?

Comment: @TrimantraSoftwareSolution ..dat sounds good option but is "created_time" and "updated_time" are indexed ?

Comment: I Don't think so you can perform indexing on this data. But you can filter posts with **since** and **until** parameters. (ex. /me/feed?fields=from,updated_time&since=1376107190)

Comment: you can get posts for updated time with FQL. possibly this tread can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10173044/filtering-facebook-users-profile-feeds-by-updated-time