# How can i get Facebook post modified time

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Currently am working with a poller that can fetch Facebook post and Facebook post comments. my poller is working in a specific time interval.current problem is if one post is already polled  in it is not polling in next time it have any new comments.

example :- poller starts from 10 AM . it will fetch all post and comments before 10 AM next time poller running after 30 minutes that time pole will fetch new post from 10 -10:30 not fetching posts that have new comments .

Is there any solution for finding post have a update in between this time interval.

Comment: plz edit any modification is wanted

Comment: @Joe i seen this solution with FQL i am looking for Graph api solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i got answer from this stack over flow post
[Filtering Facebook users Profile feeds by updated_time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10173044/filtering-facebook-users-profile-feeds-by-updated-time)

It's possible using FQL.

For example, modifying an example on the Facebook Developers site, you can retrieve the current user's posts to the her wall/feed updated before December 30, 2009 at 12am EST like so:

```
SELECT post_id, actor_id, target_id, message FROM stream WHERE source_id = me() 
AND updated_time < 1262196000 LIMIT 50
```

To my knowledge you can't filter by updated_time using the Graph API.